# Forge Viewer / 3DS Max

Tags: 3dsmax, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, 3ds

I am currently using Revit and .rvt files for my Forge Viewer projects and I am retrieving the Revit Element ID to retrieve the properties of the different Elements (Families) whiting the model.

My question is:

- I want to upload a 3DS Max model (.MAX), which works prefectly, but I also want to retrieve the different objects in a similar way of how I am currently doing this with Revit.

Let's say my 3DS model is named "Car", and inside this model I have 20 different objects/details which I can show/hide. I want to retrieve these objects. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to set show/hide individual objects in a 3DS file that has a scene/assembly.

Here is an example 3DS file where you can open the model browser, like Revit, and show/hide individual assembly pieces:

https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/viewer3d.html?svf=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/pano-raas-au/lmv/models8/turbofan/CFM.3ds.svf

Does that help?

ps. A noticed a lot of 3DS content from TurboSquid has the assembly meta-data removed, so the model-browser will appear empty.